# How can I handle 500 Internal Server Error with Selenium such that I can skip what ever iternation of the loop caused the error?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a for loop that iterates over a list of animal names from the internal center database. However, some of the animals are missing tables. I have been able to bypass this issue using Seleniums `NoSuchElementException`.

```py
s = '''\
Animal Number {animal_num} Not Found! 
Please be sure you entered a valid animal ID.\
'''.format(animal_num=i)

# Test for internal server error
try:
    driver.find_element_by_name("query_input").send_keys(i)
    driver.find_element_by_name("submit").click()

except NoSuchElementException:
    print(s)
    continue
```

However, at least one id that throws a javascript error that `NoSuchElementException` cant catch.

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\webvitals.py", line 77, in <module>
    diarrhea_observations.diarrhea_observations(driver, query_list)
  File "C:\Users\Noah Siegel\Desktop\webvitals\scripts\diarrhea_observations.py", line 32, in diarrhea_observations
    driver.find_element_by_name("query_input").send_keys(i)
  File "C:\Users\Noah Siegel\.conda\envs\webvitals\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 487, in find_element_by_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.NAME, value=name)
  File "C:\Users\Noah Siegel\.conda\envs\webvitals\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 955, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\Noah Siegel\.conda\envs\webvitals\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Noah Siegel\.conda\envs\webvitals\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [name="query_input"]
```

When I manually enter the animal id in a browser I am taken to this page
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the code you've posted is the exact code you are actually running? I would expect that the `except` would have caught that exception since you specified it. Have you added some debugging to make sure the script is running the code you think it is?

Comment: Also note that your full name is in the error path you've posted. Not sure if you mind or not. If you do want it removed, you will need to get an admin's help to remove it from the change history to be fully safe.

Comment: Agree with @JeffC above as this code should capture the NoSuchElementException and continue the execution and should not be thrown to outside.

Comment: I see the issue. After the `except` I run more lines of code but if the id is not found at the start then the next set of code throws issues. Thank you!